# How to make inner div use window scroll bar?

Tags: html, css, scroll, positioning

I'd like to use a div within my page that does not take up the whole screen use the scroll bars on the edge of the screen when its content overflows. I know that sounds confusing, so here's an example: http://www.csszengarden.com/?cssfile=/202/202.css&page=1

I would have posted code, but I'm not sure where to start on that. Could someone point me in the right direction with the HTML & CSS?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One trick is to overlay one or more static images or boxes and fix their position, then resize the scrollable area of your entire page, your inner `<div>`, such that its width fits in the "viewable area" exposed (i.e. not covered) by your overlaid area (you could use padding to achieve this).

I've made a [demo page](http://dev.NOVALISTIC.com/demos/small_scroll_area.php) to illustrate this. It does involve extra markup per my suggestion though; I'd wager that more sophisticated CSS is used to achieve the same effect with the same base markup provided by CSS Zen Garden, but my answer is just another simpler way of going about it.

The source code is provided below. The snippet is runnable but as the dimensions are unmodified from the original you will want to view it in full screen to see anything meaningful in action.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

#overlay div {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: gray;
}

/* The top and bottom "borders". */
#overlay .vert {
    height: 150px;
}

/* The left and right "borders". */
#overlay .hor {
    width: 300px;
}

/* Anchor the parts of your overlay boxes to the respective edges of the page. */
#overlay-top { top: 0; }
#overlay-bottom { bottom: 0; }
#overlay-left { left: 0; }
#overlay-right { right: 0; }

/* Your content has padding equal to the sizes of your overlay "borders". */
#content {
    padding: 150px 300px;
}
```

```html
<!-- This acts as the overlay, or mask, of your content. -->
<div id="overlay">
    <div id="overlay-top" class="vert"></div>
    <div id="overlay-bottom" class="vert"></div>
    <div id="overlay-left" class="hor"></div>
    <div id="overlay-right" class="hor"></div>
</div>

<!-- The entire content of your page would go here. -->
<div id="content">
    <h1>Top of content</h1>
    <hr>
    <p>This is a demonstration of the effect of scrolling a small content area in a page using the window's scrollbars.</p>
    <p>It was created as an illustration of <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/a/5383466/106224">this CSS answer on Stack Overflow</a>.</p>
    <hr>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. No vix everti corpora corrumpit, et mea exerci ponderum eloquentiam, vis an idque nominati. Ea mel errem conclusionemque, cu sea dicat omnesque. Facilis detracto reprehendunt mei ei.</p>
    <p>Vim aperiam suscipit ne, et has euismod senserit, est ei ornatus mnesarchum. His delicata referrentur ad, vim an sapientem molestiae laboramus, ad quem clita consequuntur ius. Pro ei sint voluptatibus. Elaboraret definitionem per cu, liber deserunt interpretaris ad duo, cu vis petentium vulputate. His at vide patrioque, in labitur alterum sea.</p>
    <p>Putent mentitum referrentur no usu. Ne autem eripuit delectus mei, forensibus persequeris vim eu, sint quaestio ad nec. Offendit aliquyam ius ex. Ex cum option noluisse. Repudiare suscipiantur est ut.</p>
    <p>Ut vero scripta argumentum per, id nemore splendide appellantur vis. Et idque aliquam praesent nec. At wisi impetus deseruisse per, salutatus omittantur ex has. No sed accusata iudicabit, eu corrumpit deseruisse eos, et vis dictas suavitate. Ad quod abhorreant dissentias duo, ius ea quando eruditi nusquam.</p>
    <p>Eos autem debet ut, vel ea omnium dolorum eligendi. Ex has magna assum iudico. Eu dictas hendrerit vis, animal dissentiunt mel cu. Cu usu nemore interesset temporibus. Mea ut adipisci praesent consequuntur, per et brute legimus commune. Pri eirmod dissentiunt ei.</p>
    <p>In nonumy nostro invenire cum. Postea complectitur sit id. An saepe animal omittam usu, quem tantas id est, nam sint deleniti in. Dicit viderer reformidans ut quo. Mei ornatus molestie ut, id dolores vivendum menandri ius. Facer possim reformidans vix ut. Et utinam possim percipitur quo.</p>
    <p>Nisl perpetua voluptaria vim et, cu per unum efficiendi, no labore instructior pri. In usu delenit intellegam, at delicata praesent eos. Cu civibus mentitum duo. Eu movet dolor vim, has cu senserit referrentur. An mel corpora comprehensam, constituto vituperata cum eu.</p>
    <p>Ne vim nemore vidisse rationibus. Id partem percipit quaerendum mel. Soleat graecis placerat cu eum, sed at dolores recteque. In sit consul appetere, cum exerci legere accommodare ad. Cum at legimus patrioque neglegentur.</p>
    <p>No alii aeque facilisis mea, his novum dissentias id. Ne his exerci feugait, mei te suas graeci iracundia. Ad paulo soluta vim, discere qualisque his eu. Ius ut fuisset offendit inciderint, mel putant impetus appellantur no. Sit ad integre officiis euripidis, libris necessitatibus at per. Tamquam insolens an duo, sed exerci electram ad, qui at doming inciderint adversarium.</p>
    <p>Cum ex ornatus accusam, vocent dolorem definiebas sit et, ut illud takimata mei. Eos ex sale brute, bonorum mediocrem an nam. Ei alienum quaestio maiestatis has, iriure vivendo cu est, pri harum periculis ex. Per ad idque populo omnesque, novum reformidans definitionem eu nec. Mel reque evertitur voluptatum ea, inani iuvaret sententiae et has.</p>
    <hr>
    <h1>Bottom of content</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: This happens to be my first non-jsFiddle demo made for Stack Overflow. I made a [jsFiddle version](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/YCBsE) but switched away because of a graphical artifact that has since apparently disappeared. jsFiddle, you so crazy.

Answer (score 1):

BoltClock answer is good when the surrounding of the div is fixed always, but when you want to use the scroll bars of the page when the div (like a modal dialog) appear on the fly it can't be used.

For this situations you can disable and hide the page scroll bars by applying this style to the body:

```
body {overflow:hidden}
```

The given div must fill the whole page and have scroll bars:

```
div {position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; overflow-y:scroll}
```

now the div scroll bars appears exactly where page scroll bar existed and it's content would be scrollable.

when the div is closed the body overflow style must be reset.

look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rahbari/kxoexa5s/