# CSS overflow and having the browser native scrollbar to be used

Tags: html, css

I have a DIV section with the css

```
#all_messages{
position:inherit;
overflow:auto;
height:100%; 
width:100%;
}
```

I want to make it scroll inside the page which i did with the overflow but i don't want an extra scrollbar on the page, i would like native browser's scrollbar to control that not one scrollbar just for that section

[image: screenshot]

Ok so in the picture you can see i have two scrollbars i want to remove the inner scrollbar and have it controlled by the browser's native scrollbar

Comment: really have no idea what you are saying, can you explain further? is the inner div forcing the window to have a scrollbar?

Comment: It sounds like #all_messages is superfluous with body...so, I'm not sure you need anything except to take away all_messages

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make inner div use window scroll bar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383394/how-to-make-inner-div-use-window-scroll-bar)

Comment: Can't understand what you're asking for...

Comment: so if you check out the screeenshot it should make more sense now

Comment: Why do you need the extra div? I don't get it.

Comment: @boltclock it is one div, and the browser scrollbar, so it is the overflow:auto; scrollbar and the a native browser scrollbar and i want to remove the scrollbar from the overflow and have the browser scrollbar control it

Comment: See if the duplicate link helps you.

Comment: @boltclock i wouldn't have asked the question if the related links helped me js

Comment: so why do you need the extra div if it 100% tall and wide and scrolls? wouldn't a window just do the exact same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to do is make all the other elements on the page position:fixed. If the content in the remaining section overflows, the browser bar will appear automatically. You must also remove the overflow:auto property from that div, so that it won't create an inner scroll as well.

Answer (score -1):

Use `overflow: hidden`. This will restrict it and not show any scroll bars.

Comment: I don't want to restrict it, i want it to scroll but just using the browser's scrollbar not an extra scrollbar