# Inner div element scroll via outer scrollbar

Tags: html, css, scroll

I have a div element that scrolls vertically; the scrollbar is within the div element itself. I'd like to have the scrollbar outside of the div, similar to how a typical webpage scrollbar is. Scrollbar looks like any other webpage, but when scrolled only scrolls this particular div element.

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner"> //to be scrolled
        <!-- content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Example Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7pgyt/

I'd like the scrollbar to be to the far right, in the red area. The scrollbar scrolls the blue area. Can this be accomplished in just HTML and CSS?

A possible outcome would be as below:

[image]

Comment: this is not possible with css... and also with jquery very deep coding required....

Comment: using `css` it do not work

Comment: Explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383394/how-to-make-inner-div-use-window-scroll-bar/5383466#5383466; Demo: http://dev.novalistic.com/demos/small_scroll_area.php and http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/YCBsE/

Comment: Can probably hack something up similar to this... http://jsfiddle.net/7pgyt/1/

Comment: @smerny won't work if you have a tall page: http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/7pgyt/4/

Comment: Yea that's part of why I posted it as a suggestion rather than an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the following html structure:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="top" class="bar"></div>
    <div id="outer">
        <div id="inner"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom" class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

You can use the following styles:

```
#wrapper {
    position:relative;
    height:200px;
}

#outer {
    background-color: red;
    overflow-y:auto;
    height: 200px;
}

#inner {
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: blue;
    margin:50px;
    position:relative; z-index:1;
}

.bar {
    height:50px; 
    z-index:2;
    position:absolute; 
    background:red; 
    left:0; 
    right:20px;
}

#bottom {bottom:0;}
#top {top:0; }
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/7pgyt/3/)

[Example with psuedo selectors instead of the bar divs](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/7pgyt/7/)

Comment: Prefer this answer (over SW4's) as it doesn't cover content (which prevents selecting and scrolling with mouse wheel). +1

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/7pgyt/6/)

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="outer"></div>
    <div id="inner">..content...</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
div {
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
#outer {
    border:50px solid red;
    padding: 50px;
    position:absolute;
    height:200px;
    right:17px;
    left:0;
}
#inner {
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 200px;
    padding:50px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: blue;
}
```