# Replace Content Scrollbar with Body Scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, replace, scrollbar

I want to know if there is a possibility to replace the scrollbar of a container (exp. `<div>`) with `overflow-y: scroll` to the `<body>` scrollbar.

So an example:

If I click on a `<button>`, a modal pops out containing a `<div>` with `height: 300px` and an inner content `<p>` with `height: 500px`. The scrollbar for the inner content appears. I want that if I clicked on the `<button>` the scrollbar of the inner content get replaced with the scrollbar of the `<body>`.

I hope that wasn't to confusing. Is there a known possibility?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: To clarify, you want the scroll bar on the far right of the page to scroll the content of the modal?

Comment: Please post a jsFiddle.

Comment: @DevinH. Roughlty thats right, the content scrollbar should be far right of the page and the body scrollbar should hide of course, but it shouldn't be the modal, that should be scrolled. But the inner `div`. So the scrollbar of the div if smaller as the page-fitting modal. The scrollbar of the inner div should fit the height of the viewport.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23678233/inner-div-element-scroll-via-outer-scrollbar Perhaps this is the solution you're looking for?

Comment: Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6egws25j/

Comment: @Devin H. Ah I thats a very effective work-a-round without javascript etc. This was the logical spark that I was looking for. :) You can post this so that you can get your reputation. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the comments above, here is a solution to your problem:

[Inner div element scroll via outer scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23678233/inner-div-element-scroll-via-outer-scrollbar)