# How to let only content scroll and rest stays the same

Tags: html, css, scroll

I have some troubles to receive an only scrolling content.
I have a bottom list on top, my scrolling content in the middle, and a xAxis directly below my scrolling content (needs to be "attached" to the scrolling content).

My scrolling content should scroll, if it is bigger than the page. If not, the scrollbar should disappear and my xAxis should be below the scrolling content (not fixed to the bottom).

This is what I have so far:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<button type="button">1 HR</button>
<button type="button">2 HR</button>
<button type="button">3 HR</button>
<button type="button">4 HR</button>
<button type="button">5 HR</button>

<div id="outer">
    <div class="content">
        <myChart></gantt-chart>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="xAxisOfMyChart"></div>
```

And:

```
#wrapper {
   position: relative;
   height: auto;
}

#outer {
   margin-top: 20px;
   overflow-y: auto;
   overflow-x: hidden;
   height: 100%;
}

.overflow-container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    height: 80%;
    z-index: 1;
 }

#wrapper:before,
#wrapper:after {
   z-index: 2;
   position: absolute;
   content: "";
   display: block;
}

#wrapper:after {
   bottom: 0;
}

#wrapper:before {
   top: 0;
}
```

Basically I oriented myself on:
[Inner div element scroll via outer scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23678233/inner-div-element-scroll-via-outer-scrollbar)

and the [fizzle](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/7pgyt/7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your content a fixed height and then `overflow-y:scroll;` See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dbphwzts/) or run the snippet. for the purposes of the example i made the body 600px high and the content 450px high. the graph is greater than 450px high.

```css
#wrapper {
   position: relative;
   height: auto;
}

#outer {
   margin-top: 20px;
   overflow-y: auto;
   overflow-x: hidden;
   height: 600px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}

.content {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    height: 450px;
    background-color:red;
    overflow-y:auto;
    z-index: 1;
 }



#wrapper:before,
#wrapper:after {
   z-index: 2;
   position: absolute;
   content: "";
   display: block;
}

#wrapper:after {
   bottom: 0;
}

#wrapper:before {
   top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<button type="button">1 HR</button>
<button type="button">2 HR</button>
<button type="button">3 HR</button>
<button type="button">4 HR</button>
<button type="button">5 HR</button>

<div id="outer">
    <div class="content">
        <myChart><img src="https://www.virtualboss.net/screenshots/images/ganttchart.gif"></myChart>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="xAxisOfMyChart"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the position as fixed for those elements which you dont want to be scrolled ...like u can fix the background div without making others as fixed...

Comment: But when I set my xAxis fixed and the scrolling element is very small, the xAxis will be not directly near the scrilling element, will it?

Comment: suppose if u want to fix x-axis  and scroll all other elements ...then just make it fix like ....             .xAxisOfMyChart{ posion:fixed;}   the fixed content will remain fix on screen upon scrolling in any dimension...an other elements will scroll by default..